# nmap won't run as sudo when installed through snap

Tags: networking, sudo, snap, nmap

I've installed nmap through the snap store with the following command:

```
$ sudo snap install nmap
```

This has worked fine and I can run nmap as a normal user.

```
$ nmap --version
Nmap version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org )
```

However, I need to run nmap as sudo as this enables a function that I require.

When running the same command as sudo I get `nmap: command not found`

```
$ sudo nmap --version
sudo: nmap: command not found
```

This doesn't happen if I install nmap through apt, but the version in apt is out of date and has a bug which stops it from working correctly.

How can I get nmap (when installed with snap) to run as sudo?

Comment: Is `/snap/bin` in your sudoers `secure_path` ?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between Stack Exchange sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @steeldriver no it wasn't... it is now! Thanks! If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @kyrofa Sorry - I've deleted the questions on the other sites. I wasn't aware of this policy and it was on topic for all three communities.

Comment: No apology necessary, I figured you weren't aware. Thanks for taking action!

Answer (score 0):

`/snap/bin` wasn't in my sudoers `secure_path`

To view/edit this, use `sudo visudo` and append `:/snap/bin` to the `secure_path` line:

```
Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

(Thanks to steeldriver for the solution in the comments)